# How to import all English words to a set in Swift/Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, set

I'm just learning and working through the Apple Xcode/Swift guide, and am currently working on the "Apple Pie" project (in case anyone is familiar). If you're not, it's a "hangman" style game, where you guess the letters in a word each round, and have a total number of guesses before you lose. The guide asks you to add your own list of words to an array, but that feels tedious and boring. I know this is just a guide to help me learn, but I think it'd be a lot more fun to pull a random word from a set of "all" English words (at least several thousand) to guess from.

How would I go about importing a set of words like this, to where I don't have to type them all hard coded? I found references to an "npm" that seems to contain what I'm looking for, but have no idea what an npm is or how to add it to my program as a searchable set.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to pull a request to a web were many english words are stored, for example: http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_caps.txt, create a file inside your app with all that words and then create an array in code where you can choose randomly from.

Comment: Another alternative would be to have a text file, and a delimiter for each word in the text file. For example, each return character signifies the end of a word, or you put like a period or a '&' at the end of each word. The next step would be to write an algorithm that iterates through each character, searches for the delimiter, and appends each word to an array (a 2D array; arrays of characters appended to an array)

Comment: There is no need to do all that, there is a function in swift 'split()' that already does that for you, if gets all the string and converts it into a 2D array of words automatically

Comment: I figured this would be used for more along the lines of reusability. Then it wouldn't just OP who could alter what words are used, it could be anyone with a guide.